# Minecraft - How do I use Pressure Plates to teleport on my Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently started my own server for friends running the modpack "The Pixelmon Modpack" on Curseforge. In order to add more flavor to the pack, I also decided to download a custom map called Pixelmon Open World Adventure. Now, one of the main features of this map is that you can use a "Railway" system (Which is really just 12 separate pressure plates that you step on and TP) in order to get around to the different villages. I loaded the map fine in Singleplayer, and the pressure plates worked. When I load the map in Multiplayer, the first village spawns all well and good, but the pressure plates don't do anything. No TP, no action, nothing at all. I have no idea what to do as I've never dealt with MC servers and editing permissions, nor do I know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following into the server properties file + restart the server

```
enable-command-block=true
```

The problem was that command blocks just... didn't work I guess, and the pressure plates relied on them. Adding that small command to the properties allowed the plates to start working again.

Comment: Try using the command /gamerule commandblocksenabled true

Comment: @Redstoner1635 That's a Bedrock Edition command. The question is asking about Java Edition.